# VS Express 2012 - Can not debug

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm following a tutorial on Virtual Studio Express 2012 to create windows 8 application.
My application start, that not the point, but I've nothing to debug it. 
I placed a "console.log" on a trigger, and I know that the trigger is working but there is no console message... and no DOM explorer either.
Does anyone have an idea, because debugging something without debugger is hard !

Here is my code for my default.js

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: cette application vient d'être lancée. Initialisez
            // votre application ici.
        } else {
            // TODO: cette application a été réactivée après avoir été suspendue.
            // Restaurez l'état de l'application ici.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {

            document.getElementById('boutonPourOuvrir').onclick = function () {

                console.log('Salut !');

            }
        }));
    }
};

app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
    // TODO: cette application est sur le point d'être suspendue. Enregistrez tout état
    // devant être conservé lors des suspensions ici. Vous pouvez utiliser l'objet
    // WinJS.Application.sessionState, qui est automatiquement
    // enregistré et restauré en cas de suspension. Si vous devez effectuer une
    // opération asynchrone avant la suspension de votre application, appelez
    // args.setPromise().
};

app.start();
})();
```

And this a screen from what I'm viewing when I launched my application : [sorry it's in French]
http://sdz-upload.s3.amazonaws.com/prod/upload/demo8.jpg

Thanks you !
H4mm3R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to VS2013 where I didn't have the problem, but I created it with changing a value. 
So here the answer for the "bug"
Go to the property of the project > debug > debug type and chose "script only"